# Compute the homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let X be the space obtained by removing two out of three coordinate axes from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. I don't know how to compute its homology group. Actually I even don't know how to find the n-simplices.

Can anybody show me in details?

Comment: Can you identify any known space which is homotopically equivalent to the given space??

Comment: Try to deformation retract onto something smaller and easier to understand. For example, do you know how to solve the analogous questions involving 1) removing a point from $\mathbb{R}^2$ or 2) removing a single axis from $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I know it can deformation retract to a shpere with 4 points removed, but I don't know what to do next

Comment: What do you know about a sphere with two points removed? Then try three.

Comment: Is it equivalent to the wedge sum of 2n-1 circles? It's just my guess.

Comment: A sphere with $n$ points removed is homeomorphic to an open disk with $n-1$ points removed, which is homeomorphic to how many circles wedged together?

Comment: I think that will be n-1 circles wedged together